# Polymer inception: styling

Tags: css, polymer

I'm working with some Polymer "inception", where I have my index page importing a Polymer element that has some other Polymer elements inside of it, of which a core-header-panel and a core-toolbar are part of them.

Just to clarify:

**index.html:**

```html
...
<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <some-polymer></some-polymer>
</body>
...
```

**some_polymer.html:**

```html
...
<style>
    core-header-panel {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
       -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
    core-toolbar {
        background: #000000;
    }
</style>
<core-header-panel>
    <core-toolbar>
        <!-- Proper elements and settings here -->
    </core-toolbar>
</core-header-panel>
...
```

*All the imports are fine and the styling is set.*

However, I'm facing a problem: the core-header-panel is not being shown.

As we know, in order to make the panel to work, we have to set body/html and core-header-panel heights at 100%, but this doesn't seems to work if we are importing and using the panel inside a Polymer element.

The only way I could make the panel to work was to set a height not by percentage. For instance, 500px. But then I'll be wasting site's flexibility. It will be stuck on that height.

So I would like to know if there's any other way to solve my problem.

Comment: Have you made the `some-polymer` block level (e.g. `display:block`)? `:host {display: block; height: 100%;}`

Comment: @ebidel, I've tried this already, but it didn't work.